# Lynx UTF-8 support

Tags: utf-8, lynx

I am using Lynx on OS X 10.11. However, it does not print UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters, but rather either an ASCII representation of them, or the `ef bf bd` "replacement" character (?).

I have been studying [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102376/do-any-text-based-web-browsers-support-unicode-box-drawing-characters) for help.

The output from the `locale` command:

```
locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

When I run Lynx with

```
lynx http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt
```

here is what the display appears like:

[image: Lynx displays UTF-8 test page incorrectly]

According to the posts in the article, Lynx should print UTF-8 properly.

`lynx -dump ...` prints the same.

(running `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` doesn't help either.)

What is strange, is that if I run with the `-mime_header` argument, eg:

```
lynx -mime_header http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt
```

It prints the characters properly. (Albeit, as a dump rather than opening in a browser environment):

[image: Lynx displays UTF-8 test page correctly]

EDIT:

Forgot to mention,

`-assume_charset=utf8` and `-assume_unrec_charset=utf8`

don't help either.

EDIT:

Well I am able to get the output I want by hard-setting CHARACTER_SET in lynx.cfg.  Though this seems like a bit of a workaround, as in the documentation it states:

```
# ...  The 'o'ptions menu setting will be stored in the user's RC
# file whenever those settings are saved, and thereafter will be used as the
# default.  ...
```

However, the setting only persists for the session it is set in. That won't work for me as I am primarily using `lynx -dump` in a script.  But as I pretty much am only UTF-8, I guess I can live with the hard setting for now.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. I suggest deleting it and reposting in [unix.se]. (FWIW, it works for me on Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 9):

I do think you should use

`lynx -dump --display_charset=utf-8`

rather than hard-setting the config file

so

`lynx --display_charset=utf-8 http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt`

alternatively

check 
https://www.brow.sh/